# CORB: Cross-Origin Read Blocking on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, htmx, cross-origin-read-blocking

I added https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.3.3/dist/htmx.min.js.gz to my jsfiddle, but now  I get:

> CORB: Cross-Origin Read Blocking

[image: js-fiddle-cors]

Is there a way to work around this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thomas_guettler/7cLy8m5u/3/

Code:

```
<button 
hx-get="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guettli/html-fragments/main/fragments/simple-div.html">

 Press me
</button>
```

---

If I use this URL: https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.3.3/dist/htmx.min.js

then I get

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guettli/html-fragments/main/fragments/simple-div.html' from origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: You could use a cors-proxy to load the content. Check this out: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: @quicVO please post your comment as answer, then I can up-vote it. And please add some explanation why your solution solves the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work-around.

If I use a mocky endpoint, then it works.

For example: https://run.mocky.io/v3/6f4b9b4c-4ac9-44e0-89fa-da7d222346df

I guess this http header in the response of github makes the browser reject the snippet:

> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin